# Why should investors be compensated for accepting systematic risk?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk, asset-pricing

> Investors should be compensated for accepting systematic risk, as it cannot be diversified.

Why do the investors need to be compensated for accepting systematic risk? Because no one can avoid it and nothing can be done to prevent it. I understand that if not given a suitable return, no investor would accept the systematic risk. But why compensate? And who is going to compensate them?

Comment: The compensation takes place by means of discounting. For example if "everyone agrees" that a stock is worth 10 a share a year from now but is risky, it will sell for 9 a share today so  the buyers get compensated 1 dollar for holding it one year,  assuming the forecast come true.

Comment: @nbbo2, if we assume the forecast of 10 comes true, we are talking about a risk-free investment. Then we are discounting because of the time value of money; a risk-free investment still gets a positive return because of the delay. When discussing risky investments, on the other hand, we do not assume the price will be equal to its expected value. Then we are discounting not only because of time but also because of the risk that we might end up with something else than 10.

Comment: Yes, it is important to distinguish between time discounting and risk discounting. My example is too simple to include this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your premise is mistaken. You *can* avoid systematic risk by investing in a risk-free asset or one that has no systematic risk (e.g. under the CAPM, that would be an asset $i$ with $\beta_i=0$). Since investors are typically risk averse and they have the choice of investing risk free, they will take on systematic risk only if they get some extra compensation for that. The compensation comes in terms of positive expected return in excess of the risk-free rate.